# I want to trim my url and want to asign certain part into a php variable

Tags: php

This is my URL

```
mysite.com/somename
```

I want to assign somename to a php variable and I don't want to use any get method

Comment: What have you already tried, what problems did you encounter?

Comment: you can do that if you use `slimframework` where you don't have to use any get

Comment: That means you have that as a string like `$url = 'mysite.com/somename'` and want to manipulate it? Or your site is accessed via that URL?

Comment: PHP_SELF variable might work.

Answer (score 2):

You can achive with `htaccess` something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?name=$1
</IfModule>
```

#### index.php

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$somename = substr($url, stripos($url,'/') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` would work for you?
[$_SERVER doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out:

```
$datum = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url_detail = pathinfo($datum['path']);
print_R($url_detail);
```